# access methods from protocols to viewcontroller

Tags: swift3, protocols

[image]I was just implementing object class to access methods and protocols. Following

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SVProgressHUD


protocol ParseAPIProtocol:class {
    func APIresponse(responseDict: NSDictionary)
}

class ParseAPI :NSObject{

      // weak var mydelegate : MyProtocols?
    weak var delegateAPI:ParseAPIProtocol?

    class func ParseUrl(postparameters: [String: AnyObject]!, url:String, current:UIViewController) {
        print(postparameters)

        print(url)
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: postparameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON
            {
                (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                switch(response.result)
                {
                case .success(_):
                    if response.result.value != nil
                    {
                        let  jsonResult = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
                        print(jsonResult)

                    }
                    break

                case .failure(_):
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    print(response.result.error as Any)
                    break
                }
             }
    }
```

Whenever I got the jsonResult, I just want to call fun APIresponse to parse result dictionary to viewcontroller class.

I declared the method on viewcontroller and its delegate.

But when I tried to call protocol method, it doesn't give me access to the method. May be I am doing something wrong. Please look into my method.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by **But when I tried to call protocol method, it doesn't give me access to the method**?

Comment: when I tried like delegateAPI.APIresponse ,it didn't work

Comment: Have you set the delegate when you call this method, so the code where you are setting delegate for this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it there are several issues, although it's hard to tell because you don't show the relevant code in your view controller
(how you set up the delegate, how you call your parse API).

First, you never call your delegate with the result. With your current setup this isn't even possible: you define `ParseAPI` to have a
delegate (instance) member but define `ParseUrl` as a class func. I guess this is what you meant when saying "it doesn't give me access to the method".
Try defining it as a member function and then, in the success case call the delegate:

```
self.delegateAPI?.APIresponse(responseDict: jsonResult)
```

In your view controller, instantiate a `ParseAPI` instance and keep it alive (for example by storing it in a strong instance member), set its delegate,
and call `ParseUrl(...)`. This call will return pretty much immediately and later, when the request and response is handled, your delegate method will
be called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ParseAPIProtocol
{
    var parser: ParseAPI?

    func somewhere()
    {
        self.parser = ParseAPI()
        self.parser!.delegateAPI = self
        self.parser!.ParseUrl(postparameters: [:], url: "...", current: self)
    }

    func APIresponse(responseDict: NSDictionary)
    {
        print("VC got response:", responseDict)
    }
}
```

Second, the `current` parameter is never used, you can remove it. Either that or you can remove the whole delegate thing and replace the current parameter
with a callback, something like this:

```
func ParseUrl(postparameters: [String: AnyObject]!, url:String, finished: @escaping (_ response: NSDictionary?) -> Void)
{
    ...
    // success case:
    finished(jsonResult)
    // failure case:
    finished(nil)
}
```

and call it like this:

```
self.parser!.ParseUrl(postparameters: [:], url: "...", finished: { (response: NSDictionary?) in
    // handle response
})
```

You can also define your callback to have an error parameter so you can act accordingly when one occurs.

And finally, while I don't know `SVProgressHUD`, you probably wanna call `SVProgressHUD.dismiss()` in the success case, too.

Comment: Sir, I have shared the photo, you can check it is not giving the access to call the delegate

Comment: Your code completion suggestions look like it is still a class function. You need to change `class func ParseUrl(...)` to `func ParseUrl(...)`.

Comment: Now it is giving me access to call function which is declared in ViewController, but its never called ;(

Comment: Which function are you talking about? The flow should be something like what I did in the `somewhere()` function: your view controller creates a parser, stores it, sets itself as the delegate, and calls the parser's `ParseUrl(...)` function. This will call the `APIresponse(responseDict:)` function of the delegate (the view controller) if you add something like `self.delegateAPI?.APIresponse(responseDict: jsonResult)` to your parser. Of course you still need to call `somewhere()` somewhere, like in viewDidAppear(animated:) or when a button is tapped, depending on when you need the data.

Comment: self.delegateAPI?.APIresponse(responseDict: jsonResult) after this, control doesn't go to  func APIresponse(responseDict: NSDictionary)
    {
        print("VC got response:", responseDict) this method
    }

Comment: Have you really set the delegate correctly? Please check in the debugger or add a print(self.delegateAPI) before calling self.delegateAPI?.APIresponse(...).

Comment: I have created new chat room. Please join that.